# Showing a summed value of array values in my template ( jQuery or Underscore )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, underscore.js

underscore.js is handling the templating on the page, and I have jQuery on my page also.

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
orders = [{q:5},{q:5},{q:5},{q:5},{q:5}];
```

Now on the page I want the sum of q printed, but I cannot get it to work.

I tried a lot of code snippets, but none of them seem to work. The one I thought had do work is this one:

```
<td><% print( _.reduce(orders.q), function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0 ) %></td>
```

It's from the page of underscore itself.

This piece of code gives me:

```
undefined is not a function;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`orders.q` looks for a property `q` on the array `orders` -- so `orders.q` is most likely returning `undefined`, which is indeed not a function.

You probably want to pass `_.pluck(orders, 'q')`, which returns an array of the values of `q` for each item in `orders`, to `_.reduce`.  And double-check your parentheses:

```
_.reduce(orders.q, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0)
```

Comment: OK I see. I will try that. But is this a good option? Is there nothing more simplistic than this?

Comment: You can go to Underscore's [mixin catalog](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/wiki/Mixin-Catalog) or write  your own mixin for `sum`; but there's been at least [one pull request for a built-in `sum`](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/460) that has been rejected.

Comment: Thanks, the method does work, but I think I will change to a normal variable and a foreach loop. I think my innitial method will itrate multiple times trough the array. One time for the pluck, and one time for the reduce.